# How to RegEx for combinations of forbidden words

Tags: regex

I am a retired teacher and have developed a way of automatically marking short answer science questions using regex. I use a more or less standard approach that requires keywords (A, B, C, etc) and rejects forbidden words (X):

```
/^(?!.*?(X))(?=.*?\b(A))(?=.*?\b(B))(?=.*?\b(C)).{0,150}$/i
```

I would like to be able reject on the basis of 2 forbidden words (X and Y) being present but where one or the other are accepted.

So  A B C;  A B C X;  A B C Y would all be accepted but A B C X Y would be rejected. Is it possible to do this and possibly more that 2 forbidden words?

By the way, I don't understand much of regex, I just use it!

Comment: While it may be possible (depending on regex variant) it is like to be far harder than using a regex to break the input into words, categorising the significant words and then counting the words in each category.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your prospective input, this may actually even be completely impossible - is `ABCXBCX` legal or illegal, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the regex, you could use:

```
(?!(?=.*X)(?=.*Y))
```

That means `X` and `Y` cannot be present both.

The whole regex:

```
/^(?!(?=.*X)(?=.*Y))(?=.*\bA)(?=.*\bB)(?=.*\bC).{0,150}$/i
```

Comment: Thanks Toto that works perfectly - and simple and elegant!!